# Appendix package and TOC formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am having trouble with one formatting option in the Appendix package. It shows me the appendices in the TOC but I want it to add "Appendix" right before each one of them. This would be possible just adding [titletoc] to the package, but it is not showing.

Could it be that Appendix package has conflict with another package? How to fix it? I already compiled it quite some times in case that was the issue. I don't get any error while compiling, it simply doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!!

This is the code for my main thesis file (all the individual chapters are independent files). It is full of other packages, but I guess it is better to have the whole pic.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{libertine}


%%%%%PACKAGES%%%%%
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}%Adds Bibliography in TOC
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{textcomp} %For adding degree symbol as textdegree command%
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Sets indent in first line paragraphs

\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{"path for my files"}}

\usepackage{textcomp} %for unit symbols%

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
    \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=footnotesize, labelsep=endash]{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}


%%%%%NOMENCLATURE
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\newcommand{\abv}[2]{\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%STYLES%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy} %Style of the header%
    \fancyhf{}
        \lhead{\leftmark}
        \cfoot{\thepage}
        \setlength{\headsep}{20pt} %Sets space below header. Should be included in fancyhdr but it was not%
\linespread{1.3}%interlineado 1.3 es 1.5 real%
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%OWN COMMANDS%%%%%%
\newcommand*\apos{\textquotesingle}
\newcommand{\phys}{\textit{Whatever term}} %Set term%
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et.~al.}} %et al.%
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\color{red}(#1!)\color{black}} %Red color note%
\newcommand{\missref}{\note{[REF]}} %Red REF absence%
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{[Todo: #1]}} %Blue reminder%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}





\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

\clearpage
\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}
\printnomenclature[3cm] 

\chapter{Main Text}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Other Chapter}\newpage\cleardoublepage

\renewcommand{\tocbibname}{REFERENCES}
\bibliography{bib/References}\newpage\cleardoublepage

%%APPENDICES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Second Appendix}\newpage\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full, yet minimal *compilable* code? For the time being, no one can help, since we do not have any of the input files.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I am quite new to both LateX and the forum :) I edited it to a very basic input. What interests me is the result in the TOC. Thanks!!